# hyperref modifies bibliography style of ACL style files

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I need to use the ACL latex style, and I would like to use the hyperref package, but it changes the way bibliography items look like in the pdf. Minimal Working Example is the following:

- download the ACL style files http://acl2012.org/call/sub01.asp
- see the bib item styles in the pdf:

Alfred V. Aho and Jeffrey D. Ullman. 1972. The Theory of Parsing, Translation and Compiling, volume 1. Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ.

- add line `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble
- compile, and see how reference syle changed:

[Aho and Ullman1972] Alfred V. Aho and Jeffrey D. Ullman. 1972. The Theory of Parsing, Translation and Compiling, volume 1. Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ.

I did not find any option for the `hyperref` package to prevent this change, any idea is welcome

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `acl2012.sty` redefines the internal command `\@lbibitem` in a way that `hyperref` is not aware of one.  As a result, when `hyperref` is used, what gets printed is the key of the citation.

One work around is as follows.  The `hyperref` redefinition uses a command `\@BIBLABEL` which is by standard set to the default `\@biblabel` via a `\providecommand*`.  This is convenient, since `\providecommand*` will only make the definition provide the command is not already defined.  Thus what we can do is define `\@BIBLABEL` before `hyperref` is loaded, to produce an empty text.  This is achieved by:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@BIBLABEL}{\@emptybiblabel}
\newcommand{\@emptybiblabel}[1]{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

i.e. we set `\@BIBLABEL` to a command `\@emptybiblabel`, which in turn just ignores its argument.  This code is enclosed between `\makeatletter / \makeatother` because of the symbol `@` in the command names.

Putting this together in a cut-down version of the `acl2012.tex` sample document gives:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{acl2012}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@BIBLABEL}{\@emptybiblabel}
\newcommand{\@emptybiblabel}[1]{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

{\bf Citations}: Citations within the text appear
in parentheses as~\cite{Gusfield:97} or, if the author's name appears in
the text itself, as Gusfield~\shortcite{Gusfield:97}. Append lowercase letters to the year in cases of ambiguities. Treat double authors as in~\cite{Aho:72}, but write as in~\cite{Chandra:81} when more than two authors are involved. Collapse multiple citations as in~\cite{Gusfield:97,Aho:72}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Aho and Ullman}1972]{Aho:72}
Alfred~V. Aho and Jeffrey~D. Ullman.
\newblock 1972.
\newblock {\em The Theory of Parsing, Translation and Compiling}, volume~1.
\newblock Prentice-{Hall}, Englewood Cliffs, NJ.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Chandra \bgroup et al.\egroup }1981]{Chandra:81}
Ashok~K. Chandra, Dexter~C. Kozen, and Larry~J. Stockmeyer.
\newblock 1981.
\newblock Alternation.
\newblock {\em Journal of the Association for Computing Machinery},
  28(1):114--133.

\bibitem[\protect\citename{Gusfield}1997]{Gusfield:97}
Dan Gusfield.
\newblock 1997.
\newblock {\em Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

In the `pdf` the links from the citations still lead to the corresponding citations.

Comment: Thank you very much... You made my day!