# LaTeX-BibTeX : do not display shortened references in References section

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How do I get rid of the bracketed keys in oddly formatted references like this one?

[image: misformatted bibliography]

The bracketed keys like **[Rusu et al.2007]** show up in all my references, but they're not supposed to.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using the ACL 2015 .sty and .bst files available from the bottom of http://acl2015.org/call_for_papers.html.  The format is instead supposed to come out like their sample file, http://acl2015.org/files/acl2015.pdf .

I use my own biblio.bib file and I include it in my *.tex document with:

```
\bibliographystyle{acl}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Here are all the packages I use:

```
\usepackage{acl2015}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % encodage
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % encodage
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

[**Note by a reader:** A more complete answer with a patch is available at [hyperref modifies bibliography style of ACL style files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124410/hyperref-modifies-bibliography-style-of-acl-style-files) .  I can't add this as a comment because I have < 50 reputation.  I can't add it as an answer because someone closed this question as unclear.  I edited the question to clarify it but it has not been reopened.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (Cool username :-))

Comment: I dispute the reason for closing of this question. It was pretty clear to me, having gone through the same issue

Comment: Comment by @JasonEisner (who does not have enough reputation to comment):  A more complete answer with a patch is available at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124410/hyperref-modifies-bibliography-style-of-acl-style-files.  I can't add this as an answer because someone closed this question as unclear.  I edited the question to clarify it but it has not been reopened.

Comment: In light of @JasonEsiner's comment above, rather than closing this question because it was unclear it really should have been closed because it is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124410/hyperref-modifies-bibliography-style-of-acl-style-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks :) while i was trying to build a MWE i found the problem: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`. If I removed this package the brackets disappear into References

[image]

Comment: Please think of future visitors to the site and construct a minimal example that shows how to truly solve the problem, rather than just code snippets. Currently I don't understand how the removal of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) could do this, so it would be helpful if you could explain.

Comment: i don't understand either :( but just removing this package removes the brackets (see the picture above).

Comment: I can confirm that removing `\usepackage{hyperref}` fixes this issue. Before removing, references appear with a tag proceeding them, e.g. "[Jane Doe et al. 2015] Jane Doe. The Rise and Fall of Does. Journal of Fawns". After removing the package, the references correctly show without the tag, i.e. "Jane Doe. The Rise and Fall of Does. Journal of Fawns". This error was most likely caused by some conflicts between how the ACL style file is defined and the `hyperref` package

Comment: You should have the `hyperref` package as the last of the packages you load.